# Why do Clojure vector function results exclude the stop value?

Tags: vector, clojure

Forgive me for the newb question and potentially incorrect terminology.

Clojure vector functions produce values that do not include the stop value.  For example:

```
=> (subvec [:peanut :butter :and :jelly] 1 3)
[:butter :and]
=> (range 1 5)
(1 2 3 4)
```

The doc for range explicitly states this but doesn't give a rational: "...Returns a lazy seq of nums from start (inclusive) to end (exclusive)...".

In Ruby these operations are inclusive:

> (1..5).to_a
>       => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly][1,3]
>       => [:butter, :and, :jelly]

Obviously these are very different languages, but I'm wondering if there was some underlying reason, beyond a personal preference by the language designers?

Comment: There's not much to answer here. Clojure uses exclusive end indexes, Ruby uses inclusive. Props to both of them for staying consistent. Exclusive versus inclusive isn't much to argue either way. You could argue that inclusive is more "intuitive", but that depends on who you are talking to.

Comment: In Ruby, `1..5` includes 5, but `1...5` does not. Ruby does it both ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the end exclusive allows you to do things like specify `(count collection)` as the endpoint without getting an NPE. That's about the biggest difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Also it means that `(range x y)` will be a collection with length `(- y x)`. That's often more convenient than `(+ 1 (- y x))`, and java's String methods behave similarly. In fact, that's another very important reason that clojure behaves the way it does: clojure collections satisfy the java collection interfaces, which use the inclusive/exclusive scheme.

Answer (score 4):

It might be that the indexing was chosen in order to be consistent with Java libraries. `java.lang.String.substring` and `java.util.List.subList` both have exclusive-end indexes.